# Definition of minus power in cyclic group

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, discrete-logarithms

I am trying to understand Schnorr signature scheme, and in the text book there is the following computetion:

$$g^s\cdot y^{-r}\stackrel{?}{=}I$$

The context is cyclic groups, and $g$ is a generator of the group, and $y$ is some element $y = g^x$ for some $x$ chosen at random.

My question is:

> What is the definition of $y^{-r}$?

How do you compute that given $y$ and $r$.

Thank you.

Comment: It is the inverse of $y^r$. That is, $y^{-1}$ is the inverse of $y$, and one can prove that the inverse of $y^r$ is $(y^{-1})^r$. In symbols: $(y^r)^{-1}=(y^{-1})^r$. So we just write $y^{-r}$ for this elements.

Comment: Ok. That was my intuition, but how do I calculate y^-1 in a cyclic group?

Comment: If $y$ has order $n$ in any group then $y^{-1}=y^{n-1}$ because (for example) $y\cdot y^{n-1}=y^n=I$

Comment: The words "calculate" and "compute" need to be made precise, because the way you would do this depends on how your group is given to you. That is, are you working with a Cayley table, or permutation/matrix representation, or presentation, or something else? Groups are abstract objects, so before we compute with them we have to first "realise" them in a concrete way, and *then* take your element as input to the algorithm. Without knowledge of this "realisation" it's hard to answer your calculate/compute question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group and $g\in G$. For $r\in \Bbb N_0$ we define $g^r\in G$ recursively via $g^{k+1}:=g\cdot g^k$ with base case $g^0:=1\in G$. We extend this to $r\in \Bbb Z$ by taking inverses, i.e., $g^{-r}=(g^{-1})^r$.

In more fancy language: For every group $G$ and $g\in G$, there exists a unique homomorphism $\phi_g\colon \Bbb Z\to G$ such that $\phi_g(1)=g$. We write $g^r$ for $\phi_g(r)$. Note that $\phi_g(-1)$ is the inverse of $g$, so ambiguity with the notation $g^{-1}$ for the inverse of $g$ does not arise. The usual power laws $g^{r+s}=g^r\cdot g^s$ and $g^{rs}=(g^r)^s$ follow readily from the homomorphism property.

Comment: Thank you. Is there efficent way to calculate y^-1 in a cyclic group? how?

Comment: If $G$ is cyclic of order $n$, then $y^n=1$, so $y^{n-1}=y^{-1}$